# Gtk.Widget.destroy() is necessary on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

When reading the [documentation](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Builder.html#Gtk.Builder) about GtkBuilder, I came across this passage:

> A `Gtk.Builder` holds a reference to all objects that it has
>   constructed and drops these references when it is finalized. This
>   finalization can cause the destruction of non-widget objects or
>   widgets which are not contained in a toplevel window. For toplevel
>   windows constructed by a builder, it is the responsibility of the user
>   to call `Gtk.Widget.destroy()` to get rid of them and all the widgets
>   they contain.

But this applies to python too? That is when I load a top-level window I must destroy it manually?

Comment: Well if the documentation says so.....

Comment: @Mr.goosberry The python documentation for Gtk is probably auto-generated from the original documentation for C. So even if the documentation states that you need to call `.destroy()`, it's not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never necessary. But destruction of widgets has nothing to do with memory management, or at least not primarily. It is mainly a matter of existence in the GUI model. If you add a widget to a container, it remains there until destroyed. Even if you hide it, it is still there. It can respond to signals, is part of lists or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Well, sort of. You generally don't have to call `destroy()` on the window manually because it happens automatically when the user clicks the window's close button.

Comment: I auditioned monitoring the memory. And I realized that memory is libarada normally when the windows are closed.
Thus, I think this is not necessary in python.